# BeautifulSoup IndexError: list index out of range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, beautifulsoup

The error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\AMAN\Projects\Python\CoronaVirus Outbreak Notification System\main2.py", line 28, in <module>
    for tr in soup.find_all('tbody')[1].find_all('tr'):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm working on this program which will give you a real-time update about the number of new cases, deaths, and the recovered cases of coronavirus according to time (after 1 hour or 2 hours) within a state. It will also provide information about how many of them are Indian nationals and foreign nationals. The python code using bs4 is as follows:

```
from plyer import notification
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

def notifyMe(title, message):
    notification.notify(
        title = title,
        message = message,
        app_icon = "icon.ico",
        timeout = 6
    )


def getData(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        # notifyMe("Harry", "Lets stop the spread of this virus together")
        myHtmlData = getData('https://www.mohfw.gov.in/')

        soup = BeautifulSoup(myHtmlData, 'html.parser')
        # print(soup.prettify())
        myDataStr = ""
        for tr in soup.find_all('tbody')[1].find_all('tr'):
            myDataStr += tr.get_text()
        myDataStr = myDataStr[1:]
        itemList = myDataStr.split("\n\n")

        states = ['Chandigarh', 'Telengana', 'Uttar Pradesh']
        for item in itemList[0:22]:
            dataList = item.split('\n')
            if dataList[1] in states: 
                nTitle = 'Cases of Covid-19'
                nText = f"State {dataList[1]}\nIndian : {dataList[2]} & Foreign : {dataList[3]}\nCured :  {dataList[4]}\nDeaths :  {dataList[5]}"
                notifyMe(nTitle, nText)
                time.sleep(2)
        time.sleep(3600)
```

Comment: The problem is caused because you cannot index `soup.find_all('tbody')[1]` with `[1]`, this results in an IndexError because there exists no [1]. Check what exactly is in `soup.find_all('tbody')` and make sure there is something to be indexed before indexing it. Or, alternatively, catch the error with a Try/Except if sometimes the code can be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because `soup.find_all('tbody')` does not have the index 1. It is not long enough. If your code only sometimes has that index, you can use

```
try: 
  soup.find_all('tbody')[1]
except IndexError:
  # Do whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

> Tbody gives ambiguous result sometimes so, eventually, some Xpaths are recognised as "table"

```
from plyer import notification
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

def notifyMe(title, message):
    notification.notify(
        title = title,
        message = message,
        app_icon = "icon.ico",
        timeout = 6
    )


def getData(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        # notifyMe("Harry", "Lets stop the spread of this virus together")
        myHtmlData = getData('https://www.mohfw.gov.in/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(myHtmlData, 'html.parser')
    # print(soup.prettify())
    myDataStr = ""
    for tr in soup.find_all('table')[1].find_all('tr'):  #try " table "
        myDataStr += tr.get_text()
    myDataStr = myDataStr[1:]
    itemList = myDataStr.split("\n\n")

    states = ['Chandigarh', 'Telengana', 'Uttar Pradesh']
    for item in itemList[0:22]:
        dataList = item.split('\n')
        if dataList[1] in states: 
            nTitle = 'Cases of Covid-19'
            nText = f"State {dataList[1]}\nIndian : {dataList[2]} & Foreign : {dataList[3]}\nCured :  {dataList[4]}\nDeaths :  {dataList[5]}"
            notifyMe(nTitle, nText)
            time.sleep(2)
    time.sleep(3600)
```